# How can I make sure one thing matches, and one doesn't, in a single regex?

Tags: php, regex

This is simple,
but I am taking an entire directory listing (in PHP with `dir()`), and making sure it both:

- isn't "." or "..", and
- ends in a file extension .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, or .png.

Right now I have

```
function isValidFile($filename) {
    $dirDotExpr = "/^\.{1,2}$/"; //matches against "." and ".."
    $extExpr = "/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/i"; //checks file extension

    return (1
        && ! preg_match($dirDotExpr, $filename)
        && preg_match($extExpr, $filename)
    )
}
```

but it'd be nice to do it all in one regular expression. However, I don't know how to make sure one thing matches, and one thing doesn't--how can I accomplish this?

Comment: On a side note, with regards to the question for a single regex, note that putting all the logic into one regex is often not the best solution. It can hurt both readability and speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be overthinking it. If you're verifying that `$filename` ends in .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, or .png, it clearly can't be "." or "..".

Comment: you're right, thank you.  
I suppose it's because I originally just wanted to get rid of . and .., but then later thought I should make sure the files are of the right type too since I won't be the one maintaining the directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isValidFile($filename)
{
    return (bool) preg_match('/\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$/iD', (string) $filename);
}
```

Note that I made the parentheses non-capturing, for a minor speed increase. Also merged `jpg` and `jpeg` into `jpe?g`. Also, I added the `D` modifier. If you don't, `$` will allow final newlines; a filename like "hello.jpg\n" would be considered valid. Be very aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to allow periods in your file name (except for the delimiter of the name and extension): ^[^\x2E]+\x2E(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$

If you do allow for periods (multi-part name): ^([^\x2E]+\x2E)+(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$

Convert to PHP as required...